# With AutoMapper, how to generalize custom type for all maps

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm new to AutoMapper and I can't figure out where to add an custom type to my ASP.NET Core 5 web app.  I've initialized AutoMapper in my startup.cs as follows:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

And, I've created, in my current assembly a mapping file like what I have below.

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<AttendeesAmazonBook, AttendeesAmazonBookDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.BookPublishedDate, opt =>
                {
                    opt.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToDateTime(src.BookPublishedDate)
                    );
                });
```

I do the conversion with the code below and it works exactly as I expect, however, I have DateTime types in all my mappings and I'm hoping not to have to do this with every field.

```
var results = context.Attendees.Where(a => a.Id == 1124)
            .ProjectTo<SpeakerDto>(_configuration).ToList();
```

I see examples that say it's easy to do by setting the configuration like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<DateTime?, string>().ConvertUsing<DateTimeToPlainStringConverter>();
```

But, I can't figure out, with my setup (my mapping class that implements `Profile`), where I put this cfg. in my processing.

Comment: Is there a real reason why you are storing a datetime in a string? This seems like its more the problem

Comment: `CreateMap` in a profile is the same as the one in `cfg.CreateMap`. It's just a different way of configuring AutoMapper.

Comment: I'm using the connector to MySQL which for some reason is returning to me a string for datetime. if I don't do this conversion, I get an error when the mapping executes. I'm open to a better way to handle this.

Comment: Perhaps a [Custom Type Converter](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html) would be appropriate? The example in those docs is  `DateTimeTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, DateTime>`

Comment: @stuartd I think yes a custom type converter is what I want but I can't figure out how to get that into my mapping pipeline based on the code I have above. That is, I'm a newby to AutoMapper and I don't understand where I would set the configuration.

Comment: See [this](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options) You _really_ need to understand a little better how `ProjectTo` works. Start by trying to get what you want in an EF LINQ query. Then it should be easy to translate that to `ProjectTo`.